# storing a formula written in string to int in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I wrote a formula in App.config file to get the record of 5 years. The value I added to the config file is: **`-(365*5)`.**

In the App.config I wrote it as:
**`add key="From_Days" value="-(356*1)"`**

In the program it is assigned as :
**`int End_Days = (Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["From_Days"]));`**

I am getting the following exception:
**`Input string was not in a correct format`**

It happened because `-(356*1)` is string and I am assigning it into an Int.

Please help me to get the value as `-1780` i.e result of this multiplication in vairable "END_Days".

Regards, SM

Comment: You can not s store a formula in int. Int only takes numbers, so you could maybe store the *results* of the formula being executed. But parsing formulas itself is not actually a trivial thing to begin with. At best you could maybe do stuff like store a Regex pattern or SQL Query, but especially that last one is a **very** dangerous game.

Comment: Suggestion: Simply store an actual start date in the configs (instead of the calculated days). It's simple enough to do the date diff calculation in code. This of course would result in a dynamic result. If you wanted the time frame to be static, simply store the number of days `1780` instead of the calculation that leads to that number.

Comment: You keep transposing 365 to 356. Also over the span of 5 years at one year will be a leap year and have 366 days. Better let the DateTime functions take care of this for you.

Answer (score 1):

The value in your config should be `-1780`.

```
 <add key="From_Days" value="-1780"/> <!-- About 5 years -->
```

---

Please note that 5 years is not always -1780 days. You could store number of days and then calculate the date in the past with `.AddYears(yearsInConfig)`.